# How to set focus to Grid UIElement in winrt?

Tags: c++-winrt

A Grid UIElement in winrt is receiving the GotFocus and LostFocus events, which are useful - but apparently Focus() is not a method available to Grid. How can the element be capable of having focus but not be capable of setting it? I am trying to restore keyboard focus to the main Grid of the app's UI when it is lost due to other interactions. Does anyone know how one might programmatically restore focus to a Grid that has just reported losing it? Thanks.

Comment: Grid cannot have focus. "[`GotFocus` is a routed event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.gotfocus)." This means that the parent receives the event if any of its children got focus. It's the child that got focus, not the Grid. What you need to do is find a focusable element within the grid and put focus on that. FocusManager may help you find one.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer - appears I can't mark this as the answer because it's entered as a comment, but it's the answer.